# Implement smart banner in iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, smartbanner

I have been searching for a way to implement promotional smart banners that take a user to my usual main launch activity from my website, the web code is easy, I just don't know how to do that on the application side.

So I researched that the method I need to implement in the app delegate is:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
    // Code here
}
```

But that function is deprecated in iOS9. The new one is:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    // code here
}
```

I want to send the user to the main launcher view controller, and I want to support iOS7 and up. Which func do I implement? Will implementing both call the code twice? What code do I use to just send the user to the main view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create deep links for your app. A good [link](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/) that explains how.

Comment: I think that might be a bit out of date, I don't have access to the `self.mainController`

Comment: I dont think there was a thinh called mainController at anytime. thats only an example. noone knew your app structure but you. the point is to add the urls to your plist and in the openURL method you decide where to send the user.

Comment: What if I always want to send them to the same place? I've never really had to alter the AppDelegate before that's why I'm being very careful

Comment: you need to check wht is the screen that is displayed to the user now. and depend on ur app structure you send them to the desired one. maybe by poping up some view controllers or poping up to ur root controller then re-push controllers.

Comment: the way you do that depend on multiple things. you use navigation controller, tabbar controller or none.

Comment: If i just don't code anything, just return true, will it just open the app to whatever view it was in last? I'm ok with doing that. Apple's documentation isn't very specific when it comes to this.

Comment: I am 99% percent that this wht will happen. but you need to return true/YES for this method.

Comment: but you need to add your custom urls to ur plist. search how you should add the deep links in the plist